# Extrair informações de um texto usando expressão regular

Tags: java

Boa tarde pessoal.

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma expressão regular para extrair informações de um texto. Eu quero obter apenas um parágrafo. O padrão do texto que estou extraindo é: ele sempre inicia com "Processo XXX" e "termina com uma data".

A expressão regular que estou usando é a seguinte:

```
Processo\s\d{3,3}.*(\n.*)*\d{2,2}\/\d{2,2}\/\d{4,4}
```

O problema é que ela termina no último bloco. Eu gostaria de obter apenas o parágrafo completo.

Exemplo de um texto a ser extraído:

Processo 001
Incluído
em pauta para 01/03/2016, às 08:30. Ficam cientes 
os advogados de que a intimação do acórdão 
dar-se-á na própria sessão de julgamento, nos termos 
do art 47 do regimento Interno da Turma Recursal. 
02/03/2015
Processo 001
Incluído em pauta para 01/03/2016, às 08:30. Ficam 
cientes os advogados de que a intimação do acórdão 
dar-se-á na própria sessão de julgamento, nos termos 
do art 47 do regimento Interno da Turma Recursal. 
02/03/2015

Ao executar a expressão neste texto, tudo é selecionado.

Comment: Sua regex não funciona, poste o texto de entrada e o texto e os dados que você deseja extrair que eu lhe ajudarei, até o momento pelo que eu percebi voce terá que utilizar a pontuação grafica para extrair a mensagem! `Processo\s*\d{3,3}.*?\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4}.*?\.(.*)?\.`

Comment: David, realmente não está funcionando. Segue a expressão: Processo\s\d{3,3}.*(\n.*)*\d{2,2}\/\d{2,2}\/\d{4,4}

Comment: Poste todo o texto que deseja analisar, e os resultados que precisa obter, no seu texto tem 2 frases, você quer elas separadas? enfim, detalhe mais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Processo.+?((?=\\n?Processo)|(?>\\d{4}$))
```

Link de onde encontrei a solução: http://www.guj.com.br/t/extrair-informacoes-de-um-texto-usando-expressao-regular/321491